# Sim chooser functionality not working in my Android App for different users from past week

Tags: android, dual-sim

If the user has dual sim and has not selected any one as default sim, the sim chooser is coming disabled in my android app. It's happening on different OS versions (11,12,13).

Occuring in other android apps as well.

Call functionality is working fine if the user selects any one sim as default.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's some problem with update Google Phone caller app. Go to data storage settings of Google Phone application and "Clear Data". It's gonna solve your problem.

Comment: It is not solved on 'clear Data' in my jio phone, please update if you have any other solution...thanks in advance

Comment: I got a solution..I think you are right,problem is in Google Phone App, if I uninstall this app..it is still in install state and ask for update...and if I don't update and check the popup..then I will be able to select sim..

Answer (score 0):

At present, I have also found this problem, and the feedback is all redmi mobile phone, and I have not found a good solution yet, hope to have a solution as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).